# Cross browser text to speech Javascript library

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, text-to-speech, html5-audio

I wanted a text to speech feature in my application.I saw Jtalk, speak.js and Google TTS.Google TTS definetely sounded better but it did not work in my chrome.

Another person recommended SoundManger So my question:

- can SoundManager or SoundManager2 be used for text to speech or is it just for playing audio files.
- Is it Cross browser or client have to have any plugin.
- If not is there a cross browser text to speech Javascript library

Thanks

Comment: I am sure this has been asked before on SO

Comment: If Google's product doesn't work on Chrome, there's a chance you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Juhana when it works in safari and not in chrome, I know it has to do with missing browser plugin. That is why I am wondering is there a plugin that can work relatively more cross browser

Comment: The google TTS engine is still not official as far as I know, it checks the HTTP referer and if it doesn't like what it holds it won't work. You can make a simple wrapper in PHP (or any other server-side language) to simply request the contents of the TTS without specifying a referer, that will work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe [speak.js](http://syntensity.com/static/espeak.html) (emscripted [eSpeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/)) can get you off the ground?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Internet Explorer, this is how you do it.

```
var speakers = new ActiveXObject("sapi.spvoice");
speakers.speak("Type text here.");
```